# Elder Scrolls IV Oblivion - Which version comes with physical map?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I intend to buy the PS3 version of The Elder Scrolls IV Oblivion Game of the Year Edition and would like to know what are the edition/versions which come with a physical map of Cyrodil (much like Skyrim Legendary Edition came with a physical map of Skyrim).

I have done some research and discovered that there was a Collector's Edition, released in 2011, which comes with said map (along with another goodies). What I'm interested in, however, are the Game Of The Year releases. Does any of them come with the map?

As far as my research led me, it seems that the original release in 2007 doesn't come with it, but a rerelease in 2011 (normal release, not the Collector's Edition) does. Is that right?

Comment: I got a map with the original(Non-GoTY PC version) but it looks quite different from the Skyrim(regular 360 version) map.

Comment: If you plan on buying this from a retailer just call and ask them.

Comment: I already did it, but the retailer can't tell, because he's not sure about it and can't open the game. He told me, however, that he's selling the 2011 rerelease.

Comment: I used to own the 2006 Xbox 360 release, paper map was included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I found an used copy of "Oblivion" with Cyrodil's map and bought it.

For future reference, I took some pictures of the box and the disk:

[disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RXp9.jpg)

[side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxY3B.jpg)

[back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irWZq.jpg)

Notice in the pictures that there isn't a single "2011" anywhere, which probably means that only the original 2007 release of the Game Of The Year editions comes with the map.